# Ship placement verification function for Battleship game

Tags: javascript, game, node.js, validation, battleship

I wrote a server-side Battleship game simulator in nodeJs/Javascript:

1. A random player who begins is chosen.
2. Both players place their ships. Software recognizes if they are placed correctly.
3. One of the players shoots at a position on the 10×10 field.  If it's not the current players turn, the program recognizes it; if it's the player's turn the program checks if the player hit a ship of the opponent. If he/she hit a ship, he/she can shoot again. If a ship is destroyed, the software recognizes that...

Its source code is available at: [https://github.com/ndsvw/battleship](https://github.com/ndsvw/battleship/tree/d8cae70d647ce8afd5023cc1187cc155781f625b)

I also wrote 36 test cases (`npm install`, `npm run test`) and it works.

I would like to improve the code and want to make sure that it does always work (all imaginable scenarios).

An example: the file [`src/field.js` contains `checkShipArray(arr)`](https://github.com/ndsvw/battleship/blob/d8cae70d647ce8afd5023cc1187cc155781f625b/src/field.js#L71-L282) that takes an array like `[67, 77, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 0, 1, 2, 16, 17, 18, 96, 97, 98, 99]` and returns an object with a status 'success'/'fail' and an array of ships:

```
{
    status: 'success',
    ships:
    [
        [ 31, 41, 51, 61, 71 ],
        [ 67, 77 ],
        [ 0, 1, 2 ],
        [ 16, 17, 18 ],
        [ 96, 97, 98, 99 ]
    ]
 }
```

But the code that makes this is ~200 lines long.  My main problem:
The 2 functions `getCollisionPosOfHorizontalShip` and `getCollisionPosOfVerticalShip` do almost look the same but I can't figure out how to write it shorter.

This is the whole field.js file:

```
const PositionSet = require('./positionset');
const RandomFieldGenerator = require('./random-field-generator');

module.exports = class Feld {
    constructor(options) {
        options = options || {};
        this.SAMEPLAYERSTURNAFTERHIT = typeof options.SAMEPLAYERSTURNAFTERHIT === 'undefined' ? true : options.SAMEPLAYERSTURNAFTERHIT;
        this.REQUIREDSHIPS = options.REQUIREDSHIPS || [0, 1, 2, 1, 1]; // default: 0x 1er, 1x 2er, 2x 3er, 1x 4er, 1x 5er
        this.FIELD_HEIGHT = options.FIELD_HEIGHT || 10;
        this.FIELD_WIDTH = options.FIELD_WIDTH || 10;
        this.COLLISION_RULES = options.COLLISION_RULES || {
            ALLOW_CORNER_COLLISIONS: true // in the default field: [0,1,2,3,4,15,16] for example
        };
        this.SHIPCOUNTER = 0;
        this.SHIPPOSCOUNTER = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.REQUIREDSHIPS.length; i++) {
            if (this.REQUIREDSHIPS[i] > 0) {
                this.SHIPCOUNTER += this.REQUIREDSHIPS[i];
            }
            this.SHIPPOSCOUNTER += this.REQUIREDSHIPS[i] * (i + 1);
        }
        this.ships = [];
        this.hits = [];
        this.misses = [];

        if (this.REQUIREDSHIPS.length > this.FIELD_WIDTH && this.REQUIREDSHIPS.length > this.FIELD_WIDTH) {
            throw new Error('At least 1 ship seems to be larger than the field.');
        }
        if (this.SHIPPOSCOUNTER > this.FIELD_WIDTH * this.FIELD_HEIGHT) {
            throw new Error('The field is not large enough for all ships.');
        }
    }

    isShipAt(pos) {
        return this.ships.some((s) => s.includes(pos));
    }

    hasAlreadyBeenHit(pos) {
        return this.hits.includes(pos);
    }

    hasAlreadyBeenMissed(pos) {
        return this.misses.includes(pos);
    }

    isShipDestroyedAt(pos, opponentFeld) {
        const ship = this.ships.find((s) => s.includes(pos)) || null;
        return (ship !== null && ship.every((p) => opponentFeld.hasAlreadyBeenHit(p)));
    }

    setShips(arr) {
        const data = this.checkShipArray(arr);
        if (data.status === 'success') {
            this.ships = data.ships;
            return {
                status: 'success'
            };
        }
        return {
            status: data.status,
            reason: data.reason
        };
    }

    setRandomShips() {
        // only works for the default field so far
        const rfg = new RandomFieldGenerator();
        return this.setShips(rfg.generateField());
    }

    checkShipArray(arr) {
        // eliminate duplicates
        arr = Array.from(new Set(arr));

        // sort ascending
        arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

        // check whether all ships are placed
        if (arr.length !== this.SHIPPOSCOUNTER) {
            return {
                status: 'fail',
                reason: 'A problem occured. The following ships need to be placed: ' + this.getRequiredShipsListAsText()
            };
        }

        // Check whether all ships are placed within the field
        if (arr.some((s) => s < 0 || s > this.FIELD_HEIGHT * this.FIELD_WIDTH - 1)) {
            return {
                status: 'fail',
                reason: 'A problem occured. Ships need to be placed within the field.'
            };
        }

        // getting an array with all ships
        const data = this.getShipsOfArray(arr);
        const ships = data.shipArray;
        const shipsH = data.shipArrayH;
        const shipsV = data.shipArrayV;

        // check whether the number of ships and their sized are correct
        if (ships.length === this.SHIPCOUNTER) {
            // deep copy the requirements; for each ship of length x: decrement the value of the index x.
            // after that: check if all values of the array are 0.
            const reqCheckArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.REQUIREDSHIPS));
            for (const s of ships) {
                reqCheckArr[s.length - 1]--;
            }
            if (reqCheckArr.some((x) => x !== 0)) {
                return {
                    status: 'fail',
                    reason: 'A problem occured. The following ships need to be placed: ' + this.getRequiredShipsListAsText()
                };
            }
        } else {
            return {
                status: 'fail',
                reason: 'A problem occured. The following ships need to be placed: ' + this.getRequiredShipsListAsText()
            };
        }

        // Check whether all parts of the horizontal ships are in the same row (don't accept [8,9,10,11,12] in the default match)
        for (const s of shipsH) {
            const row = Math.floor(s[0] / this.FIELD_WIDTH);
            for (let i = 1; i < s.length; i++) {
                if (Math.floor(s[i] / this.FIELD_WIDTH) !== row) {
                    return {
                        status: 'fail',
                        reason: 'A problem occured. The following ships need to be placed: ' + this.getRequiredShipsListAsText()
                    };
                }
            }
        }


        // iterate over all ships and check whether they are at forbidden positions
        const forbiddenPositions = this.getCollisionPos(shipsH, shipsV);
        for (const s of ships) {
            if (s.some((pos) => forbiddenPositions.hasPos(pos))) {
                return {
                    status: 'fail',
                    reason: 'A problem occured. Ships must not collide!'
                };
            }
        }

        return {
            status: 'success',
            ships
        };
    }

    getShipsOfArray(arr) {
        const shipArray = [];
        const shipArrayH = [];
        const shipArrayV = [];
        const arrH = []; // Array, that contains all the position of the horizontal ships.

        // find vertical ships.
        for (const s of arr) {
            // if the position is already part of a ship, continue
            if (shipArray.some((sh) => sh.includes(s))) {
                continue;
            }

            let i = 0;
            while (arr.includes(s + (i + 1) * this.FIELD_WIDTH)) {
                i++;
            }
            if (i === 0) {
                arrH.push(s);
            } else {
                const newShip = [];
                for (let j = s; j < s + (i + 1) * this.FIELD_WIDTH; j += this.FIELD_WIDTH) {
                    newShip.push(j);
                }
                shipArray.push(newShip);
                shipArrayV.push(newShip);
            }
        }

        // find horizontal ships.
        for (const s of arrH) {
            // if the position is already part of a ship, continue
            if (shipArray.some((sh) => sh.includes(s))) {
                continue;
            }

            let i = 0;
            const currentRow = Math.floor(s / this.FIELD_WIDTH);
            // as long as the current position is in arr && if we are still in the same row => increment i
            while (arr.includes(s + i + 1) && Math.floor((s + i + 1) / this.FIELD_WIDTH) === currentRow) {
                i++;
            }
            if (i !== 0) {
                const newShip = [];
                for (let j = s; j < s + i + 1; j++) {
                    newShip.push(j);
                }
                shipArray.push(newShip);
                shipArrayH.push(newShip);
            }
        }

        return {
            shipArray,
            shipArrayH,
            shipArrayV
        };
    }

    getCollisionPos(shipsH, shipsV) {
        const collisionPos = new PositionSet(this.FIELD_HEIGHT, this.FIELD_WIDTH);
        for (const s of shipsH) {
            collisionPos.union(this.getCollisionPosOfHorizontalShip(s));
        }
        for (const s of shipsV) {
            collisionPos.union(this.getCollisionPosOfVerticalShip(s));
        }
        return collisionPos;
    }

    getCollisionPosOfHorizontalShip(s) {
        const collisionPos = new PositionSet(this.FIELD_HEIGHT, this.FIELD_WIDTH);

        // position in front of the ship and behind the ship are forbidden.
        if (s[0] % this.FIELD_WIDTH > 0) {
            collisionPos.add(s[0] - 1);
        }
        if ((s[s.length - 1] + 1) % this.FIELD_WIDTH > 0) {
            collisionPos.add(s[s.length - 1] + 1);
        }

        // rows next to the ship and in parallel to the ship are forbidden
        for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            collisionPos.add(s[i] - this.FIELD_WIDTH);
            collisionPos.add(s[i] + this.FIELD_WIDTH);
        }

        // positions at the corners are (maybe) forbidden
        if (!this.COLLISION_RULES.ALLOW_CORNER_COLLISIONS) {
            if (s[0] % this.FIELD_WIDTH > 0) {
                collisionPos.add(s[0] - (this.FIELD_WIDTH + 1));
                collisionPos.add(s[0] + (this.FIELD_WIDTH - 1));
            }
            if ((s[0] + 1) % this.FIELD_WIDTH > 0) {
                collisionPos.add(s[s.length - 1] - (this.FIELD_WIDTH - 1));
                collisionPos.add(s[s.length - 1] + (this.FIELD_WIDTH + 1));
            }
        }
        return collisionPos;
    }

    getCollisionPosOfVerticalShip(s) {
        const collisionPos = new PositionSet(this.FIELD_HEIGHT, this.FIELD_WIDTH);

        // position in front of the ship and behind the ship are forbidden.
        collisionPos.add(s[0] - this.FIELD_WIDTH);
        collisionPos.add(s[s.length - 1] + this.FIELD_WIDTH);

        // rows next to the ship and in parallel to the ship are forbidden
        for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            if (s[i] % this.FIELD_WIDTH > 0) {
                collisionPos.add(s[i] - 1);
            }
            if ((s[i] + 1) % this.FIELD_WIDTH > 0) {
                collisionPos.add(s[i] + 1);
            }
        }

        // positions at the corners are (maybe) forbidden
        if (!this.COLLISION_RULES.ALLOW_CORNER_COLLISIONS) {
            if (s[0] % this.FIELD_WIDTH > 0) {
                collisionPos.add(s[0] - (this.FIELD_WIDTH + 1));
                collisionPos.add(s[s.length - 1] + (this.FIELD_WIDTH - 1));
            }
            if ((s[0] + 1) % this.FIELD_WIDTH > 0) {
                collisionPos.add(s[0] - (this.FIELD_WIDTH - 1));
                collisionPos.add(s[s.length - 1] + (this.FIELD_WIDTH + 1));
            }
        }
        return collisionPos;
    }

    getRequiredShipsListAsText() {
        const reqShips = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.REQUIREDSHIPS.length; i++) {
            if (this.REQUIREDSHIPS[i] > 0) {
                reqShips.push(this.REQUIREDSHIPS[i] + 'x ' + (i + 1) + 'er');
            }
        }
        return reqShips.join(', ');
    }
};
```

Comment: The code that is included in my question works absolutely fine. And all the tests of the project are successful. But it was -->ME<-- who wrote the test cases. So I'm not 100% sure whether there is MAYBE a scenario that I didn't think about that does not work as it should. (placing 2 2x1 ships on a 2x2 field with special options or something crazy....) :)

Comment: all in all: It works absolutely fine but one can almost never say that there are 100% no bugs.

Comment: OK Looks good. Have you tried pasting whole file? Does it cut off? Would be easier for reviewers if you can do it. :)

Comment: ok. Was not sure about that because the file has requirements and I though, seeing it on GitHub would be easier.

Comment: my bad. I thought you wanted the whole file reviewed. Sorry about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### General feedback

This code looks okay, though it could utilize more features of [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6), like `for...of` loops and default parameters (see below for more detail). Nothing jumps out as far as a way to consolidate the code in those two methods to check the collision positions but I wonder if you could consider flipping values in one of those instances in order to find similarities, though maybe that would make it even more complex.

### Targeted feedback

[Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) could be used to avoid lines like this in the constructors:

> ```
> options = options || {};
> ```

---

Instead of using `Array.from()` in `checkShipArray()`:

> ```
> arr = Array.from(new Set(arr));
> ```

the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) can be used to avoid the function call:

```
arr = [...new Set(arr)];
```

---

The call to sort the array in `checkShipArray()` could be moved after the validation checks to avoid excess processing.

---

Many of the `for` loops could be transformed into [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops, to simplify access of array elements. I wish that syntax supported access to the index but it doesn't seem that is the case, and thus the loop in the class `Feld` (typo?) would need to manually increment such a variable if that was converted.

The functional method [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) could be used to rewrite the `for` loop in `getRequiredShipsListAsText()`- it does allow access to the iterator counter (i.e. `i`).